# How to adjusted opacity for part of a gradient in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

i am newbie.
I have spent one day searching for solution and find nothing working...
Maybe i am searching for wrong keywords. I am sorry if this is stupid question.

**Problem:**
Photoshop 2017 CC
I am trying to re-create lenses for sunglasses and then put it on face.
I have cut out lenses from frame, changed color of lenses.
The goal is to make lenses (100% opacity) 
with opacity continuously decreasing verticaly from 100% (upper part) to 40% (bottom part),
so bottom part will be semi-transparent and little of face will be visible via lenses.
I can not find settings which allow this.
I am able to change opacity of lenses only for whole lenses, not able to set decreasing opacity.

Any simple solution?
Thank You a lot!
Jenna

## 2nd question

@AndrewH Thank You very much for your attention and help. I have tried your "Here is how to add a gradient to an existing lens", but i did not get what i wanted. For better example let´s talk about gradient from 100% color to 80%color+20%transparent.

When i go to gradient overlay settings to set: left upper candle: opacity 0% right upper candle: opacity 20% , the result is not look like i expected (or i am semi-blind, sorry): the lower part is going to be full transparent instead 80% of color+20% transparent.

I did not expected settings like 0% and 20% will display end of lower part of lenses invisible - with opacity on 0%. I expected end of lenses will be with opacity 80%. So i wanna gradient transitions from 100% color to 80% color+20% transparent.

I am sorry if i am too horrible to describe my problem. I have tried to change some settings, but still i did not get result i wanted. Or did i get it but i do not see it? Cause the same results are visible different on transparent background, black or red.

See photos please. [image: lenses2]

I am sorry for wasting your time.

## 3rd question

@AndrewH Thank You for reply.
In my previous image i followed your gif tutorial:
new layer with cut out lenses from frame
add layer mask and add gradient overlay with settings:
left upper candle: opacity 0% 
right upper candle: opacity 20% (and another image with 80%)
left and right lower candles are black color.

When i put image with 100% opacity under image with 80% opacity - please see image.[image: lenses3]
If my goal is to create gradient from 100% opacity at the top of lenses to 80% opacity at the bottom of lense - how to create it? 
Cause if i use gradient overlay with those settings - result image looks like the bottom part of lenses is ending with 100% transparent (or 0% opacity) instead of 20% transparent (or 80% opacity).

If opacity is set to -20% of original color - why do i do not see at lower part of lenses any border shape of lenses? But at the lower part it looks like gradient is ending to 100% transparent?

Do i wanna something which is too difficult to reach or impossible or do i using wrong tool (gradient overlay) or settings or ... what?
I though it is easy process with Photoshop.
Thank You all.

Comment: I think you're confusing using a gradient on a layer mask and using a gradient layer style. They require different steps. I revised my answer to show steps for applying a gradient to a layer mask to keep the original lenses but the bottom will show 20% opacity.

Comment: If you use a gradient layer style, then your left side should be 100% and the right side 80%. My answer is NOT for using a Gradient Overlay Layer Style.

Answer (score 6):

**Gradient and opacities using layer masks**

1. Select the layer with the lenses. Create a selection of the lenses. I did a quick select with the magic wand tool.

[image: Selection Lenses]

2. With the lens layer selected, press CTRL + J (Windows) or CMD + J (Mac) to create a copy of the selection onto a new layer.

[image: New lens layer]

3. Select the new lens layer, CTRL + Left Click (Windows) or CMD + Left Click (Mac) on the thumbnail to select the object.

[image: Select]

4. The lens have the same selection around them. Go to Select -> Inverse. Click "Layer 1" and choose "Add Layer Mask" to hide the lenses from the original image.

[image: Layer Mask]

5. Add a layer mask to "Layer 2", then select the Gradient Tool (G). Make the top left carrot 0% to be 100% color and the right side 20% to let 20% of color below it to show through. Add a gradient to the layer mask to hide part of the lenses.

[image: final]

The top of the lenses are 100% opaque, the bottom of the lenses are 80% opaque because we're letting 20% of colors below show through.

Download PSD File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XScaOvAK_L85xcHm56PB0nCUGSHChPDh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. 
Is it also possible to replace my black lenses with lenses which are already gradient (as on your image - gradient from original image-not gradient created by me in PS)? 
But how to add opacity continuously decreasing verticaly from 100% (upper part) to 40% (bottom part) - to those lenses from image? 
Is it possible to set opacity from 100% to 40% also for cutted out gradient lenses ?

Comment: @Jenna, could you elaborate? To me it sounds like what you are asking in the comment was already answered by AndrewH? Is the missing piece of information cutting out the existing lenses from the glasses?

Comment: my question in simple way:
is it possible to set to image gradient opacity which decrease verticaly from 100%  (upper part) to 40% (bottom part) ?
Or is it possible to do only for solid colors which i filled part of image?

Comment: @Jenna, no matter how I look at it, AndrewH already answered that question. Is there a reason why that doesn't work for you? Do you need more details? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @jenna I have updated my answer. This should get you started. It's not perfect since you're also erasing the earpiece behind the lens. That could be fixed by manually drawing that piece and messing with a layer mask/opacity.

Comment: @AndrewH the OP [requested](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/101749) if you could re-upload the PSD file as the file was moved to your trash. Just commenting so you see this.